# How to Match a Multiple-lines Text Including/Excluding Some String Using Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, multiline

In recent development work, I often needed to find specific multiple-lines texts (*) by searching the code base.
*Note: Those multiple-lines texts are often back-end methods or front-end tags.*

In the following case, to **find methods which name is like `doSomethingXxx`**, I use the regular expression **`public void doSomething.+\(\) \{[\s\S]+?\}`**, and it works well (*getting the 3 matches*).

But furthermore, when I needed to find specific multiple-lines texts including/excluding some string, in the following case, **find methods which name is like `doSomethingXxx` but includes/excludes the string `456`**, I have no solution by far.

When **finding methods including the string `456`**, the regular expression should return 1 match - the method **`doSomething2`**; When **finding methods excluding the string `456`**, the regular expression should return 2 matches - the methods **`doSomething1`** and **`doSomething3`**.

Here are some failed regular expressions I have tested: **`public void doSomething.+\(\) \{[\s\S]+?456[\s\S]+?\}`** (*returns 1 match containing both the methods **`doSomething1`** and **`doSomething2`***), **`public void doSomething.+\(\) \{[\s\S]+?(456){0}[\s\S]+?\}`** (*returns 3 matches which are the methods **`doSomething1`**, **`doSomething2`** and **`doSomething3`** respectively*).

Could you help find one solution? Thanks very much.

```
...

public void doSomething1() {
    // XXXXX
    // 123
    // XXXXX
}

...

public void doSomething2() {
    // XXXXX
    // 456
    // XXXXX
}

...

public void doSomething3() {
    // XXXXX
    // 789
    // XXXXX
}

...
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/WtG6lC/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for telling me the answer. It helps me greatly.